# Zend - Unrecognized method 'current()'

Tags: php, zend-framework, dependencies

I will make it as simple as possible...

I have two entities : Pds and Specialite

Here are the two DbTable class :

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Specialite extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    /** 
    * @var $_name : Nom de la table dans la BDD
    * @var $_primary : Nom de la clé primaire de la table
    * @var $_schema : Nom de la BDD
    * @var $_adapter : Allias de la BDD dans le registre de Zend (défini dans le Bootstrap) 
    */
    protected $_name = 'ps_specialite';
    protected $_primary = 'ps_spe_id';
    protected $_schema = 'basename';
    protected $_adapter = 'db_1';

    protected $_referenceMap = array(
        'Pds' => array(
            'columns'           => 'numprat_id',
            'refTableClass'     => 'Pds',
            'refColumns'        => 'id'
        )
    );
}

class Application_Model_DbTable_Pds extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    /** 
    * @var $_name : Nom de la table dans la BDD
    * @var $_primary : Nom de la clé primaire de la table
    * @var $_schema : Nom de la BDD
    * @var $_adapter : Allias de la BDD dans le registre de Zend (défini dans le Bootstrap) 
    */
    protected $_name = 'ps_praticiens';
    protected $_primary = 'numprat_id';
    protected $_schema = 'basename';
    protected $_adapter = 'db_1';
    protected $_dependentTables = array('Specialite');
}
```

Here are the two Models :

```
class Application_Model_Specialite extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract {
    protected $_id;
    protected $_id_pds;
    protected $_principal;

    public function __construct(array $options = null){}

    public function __set($name, $value){}

    public function __get($name){}

    public function setOptions(array $options){}

    public function setId($id){}
    public function getId(){}

    public function setIdPds($id_pds){}
    public function getIdPds(){}

    public function setPrincipal($principal){}
    public function getPrincipal(){}    }

class Application_Model_Pds extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract {
    protected $_id;
    protected $_nom;
    protected $_nom_pro;
    protected $_prenom;

    [ ... same contruction as Specialite ... ] 
}
```

And my PdsMapper.php :

```
class Application_Model_PdsMapper { protected $_dbTable;

    public function setDbTable($dbTable)
    {
        if (is_string($dbTable)) {
            $dbTable = new $dbTable();
        }
        if (!$dbTable instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Abstract) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid table data gateway provided');
        }
        $this->_dbTable = $dbTable;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDbTable()
    {
        if (null === $this->_dbTable) {
            $this->setDbTable('Application_Model_DbTable_Pds');
        }
        return $this->_dbTable;
    }

    public function save(Application_Model_Pds $pds){}

    public function find($id, Application_Model_Pds $pds)
    {
        $result = $this->getDbTable()->find($id);
        if (0 == count($result)) {
            return;
        }
        $row = $result->current();
        $pds->setId($row->id)
            ->setNom($row->nom)
            ->setPrenom($row->prenom);

        return $pds;
    }

    public function fetchAll(){} }
```

The link between Pds and Specialite is :

- Pds have one or several speciality
- Specialite concerns one or several Pds

I want to get the Specialite of a PDS. Here is index action in my controller :

```
public function indexAction(){
    $o_mapper = new Application_Model_PdsMapper();
    $pds = $o_mapper->find('69000001', new Application_Model_Pds());
    $pds_69000001 = $pds->current();
    $specialiteByPds = $pds_69000001->findDependentRowset('Specialite');
    $this->view->pds = $pds;
    $this->view->specialite = $specialiteByPds; 
}
```

But the application tell me thaht current() method is unrecognized ... I'm looking to make it work since yesterday but I don't see where is the problem...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you instanciating $pdsRowset ?

Comment: Typing error... it's $pds, not $pdsRowset, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First have a look at http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/on-models-in-a-zend-framework-application/

So you're doing several things wrongly.

First `Application_Model_Pds` extends `Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract` which doesn't have a `current` method. (Only `Zend_Db_Table_Rowset_Abstract` has it)

Tell the `Application_Model_DbTable_Pds` which `$_rowClass` to use:

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Pds extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    ...

    protected $_rowClass = 'Application_Model_Pds';
}
```

In this way you don't have to pass it to the mapper:

```
public function find($id)
{
    $result = $this->getDbTable()->find($id);
    if (0 == count($result)) {
        // better return null or throw exception?
        return;
    }
    return $result->current();
}
```

Also you don't need the properties for the db fields. They should be created automatically with the names from db.

```
class Application_Model_Pds extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract
{
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = (int)$id;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    ...
}
```

In the controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $pds = $o_mapper->find('69000001');
    $specialiteByPds = $pds->findDependentRowset('Application_Model_DbTable_Specialite');
    $this->view->pds = $pds;
    $this->view->specialite = $specialiteByPds;
}
```

Note: Not tested! And I'm not sure if the relationships work. Have a look [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html) for more info.

Personally I like it more to have an independent model class like described [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html). It seems you tried to mix this concept with the `Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract` as model concept.